# Kerb4j - How to get role name from SPNEGO Token?

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, kerberos, spnego, spring-security-kerberos

I'm trying to get the role name from the SPNEGO token returned by Active Directory for use with Spring Security authorization. I'm  using [kerb4j](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j) to authenticate since my understanding is that it can get group (i.e. role) information from the token (instead of a subsequent LDAP query) by using [this code](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j/blob/0.1.2/kerb4j-server/kerb4j-server-spring-security/src/main/java/com/kerb4j/server/spring/ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService.java).

In my Spring web security config, I have the following:

```
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${app.service-principal}")
    private String servicePrincipal;

    @Value("${app.keytab-location}")
    private String keytabLocation;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll().and() //spring
                .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), 
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

@Bean
public SpnegoAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
    SpnegoAuthenticationProvider provider = new SpnegoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
    provider.setExtractGroupsUserDetailsService(new ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService());
    provider.setServerSpn(servicePrincipal);
    return provider;
}
```

[`ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService`](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j/blob/0.1.2/kerb4j-server/kerb4j-server-spring-security/src/main/java/com/kerb4j/server/spring/ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService.java) only gets a [SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-components) such as (S-1-2-20-132925241-12333....) rather than an AD group name such as ADMIN. How can `ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService` be written to extract the name of the group? Is this information available in the SPNEGO token?

**Update**

Simply replacing ROLE_ADMIN in the `hasRole` SpEL with the SID does not work.

**Update 2**

A given SID string is not matching SID string passed into `hasRole` because `hasRole` appends `ROLE_` the passed in String. Once I changed `ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService` to prefix "ROLE_" to the SID (e.g. ROLE_S-1-2-20-132925241-12333....), the matching worked.

Still though... how can I get the group name (e.g. ADMIN) in `ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService` instead of the SID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService only gets a SID such as (S-1-2-20-132925241-12333....) rather than an AD group name such as ADMIN. How can ExtractGroupsUserDetailsService be written to extract the name of the group? Is this information available in the SPNEGO token?

No, the Kerberos PAC only contains SIDs, not names. (Windows access control is never based on names.) You will still need an LDAP search for those.

Comment: Which makes the PAC data useless because all can happen offline and LDAP access will add a huge overhead to your requests. Use the SIDs, love the SIDs.

Comment: I plan to use the SIDs as @Michael-O suggested.

Comment: I recommend to map SID to logical roles in your application. This is what I do too. Works for 10 years now.